# Using cmake to include my source files to another existing project

Tags: c++, c, build, process, cmake

I'm trying to extend an open source project with my own source files, so that the executable being produced includes my code as well. Probably it's very easy, but somehow I'm overlooking it.

The build process is using cmake and the open source project contains a well written CMakeLists.txt. Instead of adding my source files in the directories of the open source project (and possibly changing CMakeLists.txt of the open source project), I prefer to separate my code in its own directory as follows:

```
src/opensourceproject/src/...

src/opensourceproject/include/...

...

src/myaddition/include/...

src/myaddition/src/...
```

Is there a way to wrap the build process and create a CMakeLists.txt that builds opensourceproject with my sources added to the opensource build? The reason why I want it, is that I'm more or less writing a plugin and I want my code to be present in the produced executable.